# Changing displayed forum roles on functions file for bbpress forum

Tags: php, function, bbpress, forums

i want to only display user role for keymaster and moderator users.

I don't want every participant to have their role shown , only the keymaster and moderators are important enough to me to show their role next to their avatar. The following function code i found, and used... It worked but has some issues:

```
function role_show () {
$displayed_user = bbp_get_reply_author_id() ;
$role = bbp_get_user_role( $displayed_user);
if ( bbp_is_user_keymaster($displayed_user) ||$role == 'bbp_moderator') $args['show_role'] = true ;
else $args['show_role'] = false ;
return $args ;
}
add_filter ('bbp_before_get_reply_author_link_parse_args', 'role_show' )
```

**Code Issues:**
On the Forums topic post lists, This code also removes the avatar from showing in the same cell section as the “last post by” . And it removes the “last post by” name in this same section. How can I fix this ?

If needed, I could implement this code again and provide a link to the error so you can see.

Thank you for any help.